# How to get the data from a selected value in a view .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm creating an application where the user can post information and see the information posted, something like a forum. I created a list where the publications stored in the database are shown, so on the main page that list is shown with the title, description, date, etc. of each publication. Now, what I'm trying to do is select anyone of the posts in the list and then display the full information of the selected post in other view. I'm using a MVC view with its respective controller to consume the API.

The code on the API controller to get the info of the selected post:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("seePost")]
    public IActionResult seePost([FromBody] int idSelPost)
    {
        PostContentModel post = new PostContentModel();

        var postContent = db.Content.Find(idSelPost);

        var postInfo = db.Forum.Find(idSelPost);

        post.TittlePost = postInfo.TittlePost;

        post.DescPost = postInfo.DescPost;

        post.CreationDate = postInfo.CreationDate;

        post.Content = postContent.Content;
        
        return Ok(post);
    }
```

With the code above I joining two different tables `Content` and `Forum` to return only a one model with the complete info of the post, to know what is the post selected the method receives an integer which is the id from the post selected displayed on the list. I've testing the method with Postman sending a number on a JSON file, but it appears that `the JSON value could not converted to System.Int32`:

```
{
   "IdPost":6
}
```

Also, I have tried to do the same by creating a model class that only has an int variable to store the id of the selected post and pass it as a parameter to the model in the `seePost` method, but it gives me the "invalid name of column... " Sqlexception.

So, I don't know how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to have a model class something llike `public class SelPost { public int { IdPost {get;set;}}}` and us it as `[FromBody] SelPost post` and then try to get id from it by doing `post.IdPost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Routing

```
{
   "IdPost":6
}
```

means that you need to accept an object with a property `IdPost`;

```
public class Post
{
   public int IdPost {get;set;}
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("seePost")]
public IActionResult seePost([FromBody] Post post)
{
   // TODO check if not null
   var id = post.Id;
```

#### OR

Just send the number

```
6
```

#### OR

Send the id in the URL.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("seePost/{idSellPost}")]
public IActionResult seePost(int idSelPost)
{
```

## "invalid name of column... "

It seems that your model seems to out of sync with the database. You need to confirm that both `Content` and `Forum` models are mapped correctly.